# Code runs faster on localhost (via POW) then on server on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, performance, localhost, webserver, rack-pow

I am using [POW](http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2.1.5) to set up my iPhone to test a web app on localhost.

The javascript performance that ran on the POW localhost on my phone is good i.e. scrolling and loading was fast.

However, when I switch over to using a heroku server to run the web app (same code base), the performance dropped tremendously i.e. scrolling is sluggish and loading is slow.

From my understanding, performance of code on localhost (uncompiled javascript etc) should not be faster than the one running on the heroku-server.

Has anyone encountered this before? What could have caused the server's performance difference in performance?

The link to my website (on heroku server) is as follows: [beta.dailymus.es](http://beta.dailymus.es) - open on mobile browser

Comment: It must be your ISP cause it's flying for me ...

Comment: @EddieB, you tried it on the mobile browser? Mobile safari?

Comment: Well that didn't do well - the browser froze -- Looking at your source --- can you cut the bootstrap size? it's fairly beasty

Comment: @EddieB, I tried tonnes of optimization i.e. unbinding events, removing unused tempates etc but didn't seem to help much. But my query is why the performance can be so much better if I run the app on the localhost via POW on the mobile browser...

Comment: I'm not providing an answer because I'm really just trying to assist ;-) However, my bet is on cache issues - could try installing [Node Time](https://addons.heroku.com/nodetime) to see if theres a hit there ... HTH